# Error while dpkg the virtualbox-5.0_5.0.4-102546-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb "Failed to create the Virtualboxclient object"?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, virtualbox

I am using ubuntu 14.04LTS.

I ran

```
$sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.4-102546-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb 
$virtualbox
```

**Error:**

```
Failed to create VirtualBoxClient COM Object.The application will now terminate.

Callee RC: 
NS_ERROR_FACTORY_NOT_REGISTERED (0x80040154)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We resolved this in chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29023/room-for-rpi-awesomeness-and-sameer-pradhan).

Quick explanation of how we resolved it:

OP had downloaded the `.deb` file from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

1. Run `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox`
2. Reboot the machine
3. Run `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.4-102546-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb`.
4. Run `virtualbox` and it now works!

Apparently a reboot was required.